# How to abruptly stop an akka stream Runnable Graph?

Tags: scala, io, akka, akka-stream, scala-streams

I am not able to figure out how to stop akka stream Runnable Graph immediately ? How to use killswitch to achieve this? It has been just a few days that I started akka streams. In my case I am reading lines from a file and doing some operations in flow and writing to the sink. What I want to do is, stop reading file immediately whenever I want, and I hope this should possibly stop the whole running graph. Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Akka Streams 2.4.3, there is an elegant way to stop the stream from the outside via [`KillSwitch`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.9-RC1/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#Controlling_graph_completion_with_KillSwitch).

Consider the following example, which stops stream after 10 seconds.

```
object ExampleStopStream extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("streams")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  import system.dispatcher

  val source = Source.
    fromIterator(() => Iterator.continually(Random.nextInt(100))).
    delay(500.millis, DelayOverflowStrategy.dropHead)
  val square = Flow[Int].map(x => x * x)
  val sink = Sink.foreach(println)

  val (killSwitch, done) =
    source.via(square).
    viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right).
    toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()

  system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds) {
    println("Shutting down...")
    killSwitch.shutdown()
  }

  done.foreach { _ =>
    println("I'm done")
    Await.result(system.terminate(), 1.seconds)
  }

}
```

Comment: See the example code below:

How to stop the following graph, and cancel reading the large file?

RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
    implicit builder =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      // Source from file
      val A: Outlet[String] = builder.add(readFileLineByLine).out

      //write each lines to file
      val E: Inlet[String] = builder.add(writeLinesToFile).in

      A ~> E

      ClosedShape
  }).run()

Comment: You are providing example such that you know when to stop the system before you start, but in my case, I need to stop the running system any time I want.

Comment: I see, from the akka stream test I go tthis working:

val switch1 = KillSwitches.shared("switch")
  val downstream = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
    implicit builder =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      // Source from file
      val A: Outlet[String] = builder.add(readFileLineByLine).out

      //write each lines to file
      val E: Inlet[String] = builder.add(writeLinesToFile).in

      A.via(switch1.flow) ~> E

      ClosedShape
  }).run()


  switch1.shutdown()

Answer (score 1):

The one way have a service or shutdownhookup which can call graph cancellable

```
val graph=
    Source.tick(FiniteDuration(0,TimeUnit.SECONDS), FiniteDuration(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS), Random.nextInt).to(Sink.foreach(println))
  val cancellable=graph.run()

  cancellable.cancel
```

The cancellable.cancel can be part of ActorSystem.registerOnTermination