# Akka Stream DSL graph KillSwitch

Tags: scala, stream, akka-stream

I am playing with Akka Streams and streaming content from a file using Alpakka. I need to stop the stream after some time so I want to use `KillSwitc`h. But I don't know how to use it because I am using the graph DSL.

My graph looks like this:

```
val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  source ~> mainFlow ~> sink

  ClosedShape
})

graph.run()
```

I found a solution here: [How to abruptly stop an akka stream Runnable Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747035/how-to-abruptly-stop-an-akka-stream-runnable-graph)

However, I don't know how to apply it if I'm using the graph DSL. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To surface a materialized value in the GraphDSL, you can pass the stage that materialized to that value to the `create` method. It is easier explained with an example. In your case:

```
  val switch = KillSwitches.single[Int]

  val graph: RunnableGraph[UniqueKillSwitch] =
    RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(switch) { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[UniqueKillSwitch] => sw =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    source ~> mainFlow ~> sw ~> sink

    ClosedShape
  })

  val ks = graph.run()
  ks.shutdown()
```

Comment: Ok, perfect :) I have one more question, do you have an idea how to stop a stream after process n elements? Now I am using system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.seconds) but better will be stop after processed defined count of element instead of time.

Comment: Don't need a kill switch for that, you can use `.take(n)`

Comment: I know, but I want to take n elements, stop the stream, call another method which does something else, after that call system.terminate(). I want to measure time how long takes to process for example 100 elements.

Comment: Still, no need for a KillSwitch. Use `take(n)`, and choose a sink that materializes to a `Future` at completion (e.g. Sink.ignore). Then you can attach any callback to the future you get back when you run the graph.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand how to do it. As a sink I am using a file and it looks like that:   Sink[String, Future[IOResult]] , how can attach callback to it? Can you please write simple sample code? Thanks

Comment: Don't mean to be pedantic, but this has evolved to a different issue from what it originally was. Could you please create another question stating clearly the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, sure no problem. I did as you proposed